How to build docker container based on Yocto image?
I want to build docker container based on yocto to create   Linux environment for Application to run on Host machine instead of actual Linux Board.
I know how to build docker container based any base docker image as mentioned into this website:
https://joeldare.com/creating-a-minimal-docker-container
Can someone please provide me steps to follow to build docker container which is built based on Yocto image to test developed Application.
I have following requirement:
we are using Yocto based build system to built Linux for target machine
so in order to test Application on some simulated environment we are planning to use docker container based on Yocto so can run docker instance on host machine to test developed Application.
It seems I have to use Docker Base Image process to build container based on yocto linux as follow however not getting from where to start

generate rootfs based on yocto
build container based on this rootfs generated from yocto
Integrate required application to launch at container startup

I have also looked into this docker image from a yocto generated image? but couldn't find process to follow

Another option would be use QEMU to run the yocto image.  It'll be slower, but it'll be exactly what's running on the target (minus the hardware peripherals, of course)

Yes QEMU I know. However currently I want to build docker container which run based on Yocto linux @RussSchultz

Seems like you want a cross-docker container something similar to cross compiler: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler#:~:text=A%20cross%20compiler%20is%20a,devices%20is%20a%20cross%20compiler.
